# Coil ImageRequest for drawable resource

Tags: android, imageview, drawable, android-drawable, coil

I'm trying to prepare Coil's `ImageRequest` as:

```
val drawable = when {
        mimeType.startsWith("image") -> R.drawable.ic_baseline_image_24
        mimeType.startsWith("video") -> R.drawable.ic_baseline_ondemand_video_24
        mimeType.startsWith("audio") -> R.drawable.ic_baseline_audiotrack_24
        else -> R.drawable.ic_baseline_attach_file_24
}
val imageRequest = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
        .data(drawable)
        .crossfade(true)
        .target(imageView)
        .build()

//blah-blah
// and somewhere deep inside code
imageLoader.enqueue(imageRequest)
```

But it doesn't work.

I suppose there should be another approach, or does `ImageRequest` not support local drawable?

Comment: It's should have worked. I can't see any issue in your code. There must be some problem in your layout. Could you please share your layout?

Comment: I tried it on my end and it's working on my end here is repo: https://github.com/ngima/CoilExample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Coil Documentation](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/getting_started/#image-requests)

> All requests should set data (i.e. url, uri, file, drawable resource,
> etc.). This is what the ImageLoader will use to decide where to fetch
> the image data from. If you do not set data, it will default to
> NullRequestData.

And It's seems like you're doing it correctly. I verified it on my end, you could checkout this [Github Repository](https://github.com/ngima/CoilExample). Where I tried to recreate the issue you've mentioned and it's working perfectly. Please review your imageView's height width or the constraints (if you're using constraint layout) layout.

Comment: You're right. Magic was in creation of `ImageRequest` with `Activity` `Context`. I was creating it with `ApplicationContext` - which is wrong.

Comment: Oh that's the reason.